# Correctly using the switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

The problem I'm trying to solve is composing a paragraph and when I say `1` my program says `thumb` on the second line of my song. When my program says `2` it should say `shoe` on my second line of my song. My program is not working as I planned and I'm not sure if I'm using the switch statement correctly inside the `for` loop or if the sequence of my program is wrong.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class SingChildSong extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++){
            println ("This old man, he played" + i);

            switch (i) {
                case 1: println("thumb"); break;
                case 2: println("shoe"); break;
                case 3: println("knee"); break;
            }

            println ("He played knick-knack on my"  + (i));
            println ("With a knick-knack, paddy-whack");
            println ("Give your dog a bone.");
            println ("This old man came rolling home.");

            println ( "" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the output you get?

Comment: Yes that is because you are printing the 'i's

Comment: its not working because I can't get the program to recognize the switch statement and print shoe or thumb.

Comment: Also, on `for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)` i is never getting the value 3. You need to update your condition to `i <= 3`for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it right you are intending to do:

```
...
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    System.out.println ("This old man, he played " + i);
    String word;

    switch (i) {
    case 1: word = "thumb"; break;
    case 2: word = "shoe"; break;
    case 3: word = "knee"; break;
    }

    System.out.println ("He played knick-knack on my "  + word);
    System.out.println ("With a knick-knack, paddy-whack");
    System.out.println ("Give your dog a bone.");
    System.out.println ("This old man came rolling home.");

    System.out.println ( "" );
 }
...
```

As you say Strings are not yet studied in your book, the correct answer, without Strings should be:

```
...
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    System.out.println ("This old man, he played " + i);

    switch (i) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println ("He played knick-knack on my thumb");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println ("He played knick-knack on my shoe");
        break;
    case 3: 
        System.out.println ("He played knick-knack on my knee");
        break;
    }

    System.out.println ("With a knick-knack, paddy-whack");
    System.out.println ("Give your dog a bone.");
    System.out.println ("This old man came rolling home.");

    System.out.println ( "" );
 }
...
```

Comment: The first println will print the i's as well... all the printlns should come after the switch case

Comment: On the second line of the song, she says.

Comment: @ManuelMiranda Your suggestion looks very interesting. I'm going to try your example. Thanks.

Comment: I corrected my mistake Manuel. I missed the second line part completely.

Comment: @nEm: Great, I think the number is to make it rhyme =)

Comment: Yes, I just overlooked the song. Probably means I should sleep!

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer. It makes a lot of sense to me now that it is very helpful. I just worked it out on my computer.

Comment: @JessicaM. Im glad it helped you, so if you could set it as the correct answer it would be cool =)

Answer (score 3):

It's not the switch statement, it's the for loop.  The loop terminates when the i is less than three, not when it's less than or equal to '<='

One lazy way to test it is by printing the value of i as a quick and dirty test.  If you want to be fancy you could add a break point and inspect the value of i during the loop.  Even better, make a JUnit test because main methods are for sissies.

```
@Test
public void tester(){
    // I <3 zero
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        String bodyPart = getBodyPart(i);
        // Dumb test example
        if( i == 0 ) {
           assertTrue( "thumb" ==  bodyPart );
        } else if ( i == 1 ) {
           assertTrue( "shoe" == bodyPart );
        } else if ( i == 2 ) {
           assertTrue( "knee" == bodyPart );
        }
    }
}

public String getBodyPart(int i) {
    switch(i){
        case 1: 
            return "thumb";
        case 2:
            return "shoe";
        case 3:
            return "knee";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that too! Completely missed that hehe

Comment: np, If you are going a lot of String concatenation, "foo " + i, take a look at String.format().

Comment: This is SO overdoing it it's funny haha

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you have not studied strings yet, then think of the order in which you want it displayed. 
And sorry I had made a mistake earlier, now I have properly edited the answer.

```
public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
            println ("This old man, he played " + i);

            println ("He played knick-knack on my");
            //print your word 
            switch (i) {
              case 1: println("thumb"); break;
              case 2: println("shoe"); break;
              case 3: println("knee"); break;
               }

            println ("With a knick-knack, paddy-whack");
            println ("Give your dog a bone.");
            println ("This old man came rolling home.");

            println ( "" );
         }
        }
```

Comment: This is a review question early in my book so I'm not familiar with getword. All the tools I have to solve this question is the for/while loop and switch statement.

Comment: I don't want to reuse the word. I think the purpose of the problem is the song counts up from 1 to 3 and for each paragraph in the song it uses a different word for each number. 1 = thumb 2 = shoe 3 = knee.

Comment: Yes, I understand. So what you want to do is print thumb instead of 1... but how do you tell the program that 1 means thumb?

Comment: that is the confusing part for me.

Comment: Do you understand now? Please do ask if you can't especially since these are the basics and very important

Comment: I understand the problem I'm just not sure how to solve it. I don't know get swith(i) to print the word instead of the number.

Comment: Do you have to get Switch to print the word?

Comment: That's not specified in the problem. But that's how I've chosen my plan to solve the problem. Strings are two chapters in the future. All I've learned so far is...for/while loops,  if's statements, switch statements  and sentinel.

Comment: I guess it was on my mind as I was reading yours, although I copy pasted the code from the question. Sorry! I am not trying to take from your code.

Comment: @nEm: no problem, just kidding =)

Comment: Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you very much for taking the time. It makes much more sense now. The solution is so simple I don't know how I didn't think of it before.

Comment: Yes your switch case just needed to be after the second line and not the first.

Answer (score 0):

You never assign the string to i, which would be fatal, since its your loop's counter variable. I guess you have to use the switch statement, so i'll post a working solution then explain why it works.

```
for( int i=0; i<3; i++){
   println ("This old man, he played" + i);
    String instrument;

    switch (i) {
    case 0: instrument = "thumb"; break;
    case 1: instrument = "shoe"; break;
    case 2: instrument = "knee"; break;
    }



    println ("He played knick-knack on my "  + instrument);
    println ("With a knick-knack, paddy-whack");
    println ("Give your dog a bone.");
    println ("This old man came rolling home.");

    println ( "" );

 }
```

The variable i is just the counter for your loop, so if you print i, you print the number.
Thats why i defined a String variable "instrument" before the switch statement, then assign it to the appropriate value (remember, the loop starts counting at 0, so you have to adjust either your cases or your loop, you could have also done for(int i=1; i<4; i++))

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
```

Your for loop block will stop at `i = 3`. Which means `i < 3` is equal to false.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have that in a run method ??
Run is a special method in [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) objects, which are used for multithreading.

For your program to run you should try and move it to another method. Try moving it to the main.

Also, you are printing i, not the word. Try :

```
public class Song{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] arr = {"thumb","shoe","knee"};

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
        System.out.println("this old man he played "+arr[i]);
    }
}
}
```

That way there is no need for a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

1. use `System.out.println` instead of `println` **OR**
2. use `import static java.lang.System.out.println;`.

Given that you are early in your book, you probably are'nt quite to `import static` yet--it is a fairly advanced construct. So use solution **1**.

```
System.out.println("He played knick-knack on my" + (i));
```

**EDIT:** Also, some other people make a good point--use `public static void main(String args[])`, not a `run()` method. When you run a Java program, it calls `main()`, not `run()`.